# PHP, unexpected { in if statement

Tags: php

This is my code which links to another file, after writing all this and test it. I get this error. I am unsure how to solve it.

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in C:\Sanjay\Index.php on line 11

```
<?php
include_once("DB.php");

//make code insert image to database
if (isset($_POST['save']))
{
    if(($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/gif')
    ||(($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpeg')
    ||(($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/pjpeg')
    && ($_FILES['file']['size'] < 2000000))
    {
        if ($_FILES['file']['error'] > 0)
        {
            echo "return code:" . $_FILES['file']['error'];
        }
        else if(file_exists('upload/'.$_FILES['file']['name']))
        {
            echo $_FILES['file']['name']."Already Exit";
        }
        else if (moved_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
                'upload/'.$_FILES['file']['name']))
                {
                    $part = $_FILES['file']['name'];
                    $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO tblstudent
                                            (studentname,gender,pob,address,status,photo)
                                        VALUES('{$POST['studentname']}',
                                                '{$POST['gender']}',
                                                '{$POST['pob']}',
                                                '{$POST['address']}',
                                                '{$POST['status']}',
                                                '{$part}')");
                    if ($sql)
                    {
                        echo "successfully insert this record.....";
                    }
                }
    }
}
//end
?>
```

Comment: Add two closing parentheses to your super long conditional

Comment: You have 7 `(`, and only 5 `)` in that if()...

Comment: `( = 7x`, `) = 5x`  anymore questions?

Comment: Usually it's helpful to post things you've tried that didn't solve your problem, as well as a statement about what you're actually trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 4):

You missed two `)`. Try this

```
if(($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/gif')
    ||(($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/jpeg')
        ||(($_FILES['file']['type'] == 'image/pjpeg')
            && ($_FILES['file']['size'] < 2000000)
        )
    )
)
```

Comment: Such as simple mistake hehe, now it's working, thank you very much

Comment: why not: if (in_array($_FILES['file']['type'], ['image/gif', 'image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg'], true) && $_FILES['file']['size'] < 2000000)

Comment: @OIS I was just thinking the same thing. That would seriously reduce that super long if statement

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you miss one closing ")" on line 10. It is usually a good idea, to move complex statements (like the one in your if) to separate function (it makes code more readable).